# FFmpeg Brrip or Dvdrip To Mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I want to compress a film which has dvdrip and brrip with mp4 and h.264 codecs.

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -acodec libfaac -vpre slower \
  -acodec copy video.mp4
```

error message

```
Invalid option or argument: 'directpred=3', parsed as 'directpred' = '3'
```

[Console output](http://pastebin.com/kD3HGDe7)

Comment: Sounds like fun. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I could not do it correctly. Their sizes increase four times generally

Comment: [code]ffmpeg -i video.avi -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -acodec libfaac -vpre slower -acodec copy video.mp4[/code] 
error message:  Invalid option or argument: 'directpred=3', parsed as 'directpred' = '3'

Comment: Please provide the complete console output. I am guessing that you are using a newer version of ffmpeg that does not use the old text file based presets, and perhaps you copied the "slower" preset from somewhere and just expect ffmpeg to use it, but I won't know for sure without the ffmpeg console output.